# How To Place AppBar Title in Left Side in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

Here is my code for AppBar Tittle, but it not Working

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context){
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
      child: new Text("App Name"),
    ),
  ),
);}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Transform is the widget used for forcefully translating widgets in the x-y-z dimensions.

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: false,
          titleSpacing: 0.0,
          title:  Transform(
              // you can forcefully translate values left side using Transform
              transform:  Matrix4.translationValues(-20.0, 0.0, 0.0),
              child: Text(
                "HOLIDAYS",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: dateBackgroundColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ),
      );
```

Comment: If any one using with `SliverAppBar -> FlexibleSpaceBar` also set `centerTitle: false` in `FlexibleSpaceBar` too.

Comment: You can also use negative values for title spacing.

Comment: @Nilesh Athghara's answer is the most elegant answer and contains a working example. I recommend this over the older answer above.

Answer (score 42):

Set the `centerTitle` property to false.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work without setting `leadingwidth`

Answer (score 24):

set the `centerTile` property to false and `leadingWidth: 0` in AppBar

Comment: to get the same dimensions of leading widget: 
leadingWidth: NavigationToolbar.kMiddleSpacing,

Answer (score 10):

Simply set the `centerTile` property to `false` in AppBar widget.

```
 AppBar(
        ...
        centerTitle: false,
        title: Text("App Name"),
        ...
        )
```

Answer (score 8):

AppBar title by default is in center positioned. To make text on left you should set property centerTitle false, like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      centerTitle: false
      title: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
        child: new Text("App Name"),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show title to very left of appbar

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      centerTitle: false,
      leadingWidth: 0, // this is also im
      title: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
        child: new Text("App Name"),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

will force text to very left of the appbar

Answer (score 3):

```
appBar: AppBar(
  centerTitle: false,
  backgroundColor: Color(0xff98A8D0),
  title: Image.asset(
    'assets/covalent_dark_icon.png',
    height: 45,
    width: 120,
  ),
)
```

This is the actual way. Using Transform will make your UI less responsive.

Answer (score 2):

For me specifing `automaticallyImplyLeading: false` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `titleSpacing` for left offset(padding). But it’s not best approach i just want to show another way.

```
AppBar(
           ...
           centerTitle: false,
           titleSpacing: -40,
           title: Text("App Name"),
           ...
           ),
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: You should add explanation..

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me as I had two lines of text and each line has a different style, my solution was to use a RichText to correctly align the text to the left, and use different styles for each line. If I didn't use the RichText and just put two Text widgets inside a Column, no matter what I did the text still aligned centre, just on the left side of the AppBar.

```
    appBar: AppBar(
    centerTitle: false,
    titleSpacing: 16.0,
    title: RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: "Good morning,\n",
        style: textTheme.bodySmall,
        children: [
          TextSpan(
            text: "Alexandra",
            style: textTheme.headlineSmall,
          ),
        ],
       ),
     ),
    ),
```